# Usage of leather products from cowhide

Tags: karma

We use leather products made from cowhide, such as wristwatches, bags, shoes and belts. Now is it that those who are killing the cow, those who are preparing the cowhide and those who are using the finished products, are they bound to face rebirth as karma? (according to the scriptures)?